# Display ZSH brace expansion

Tags: zsh

Is there a way to show the expanded version of a brace expansion statement?

For example, I have:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:{drop,create,migrate}
```

Does the expanded version expand to this?

```
$ bundle exec rake db:drop
$ bundle exec rake db:create
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could always just do

```
~  for i (drop create migrate) echo bundle exec rake db:$i
bundle exec rake db:drop
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Or

```
~ echo bundle exec rake db:{drop,create,migrate}
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: The second answer is what I wanted to see. I thought it expanded the longer version with three separate statements instead of your single statement. Thanks!

Comment: I modified the question a little, my original question wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 3):

For it show as those 3 lines, you'd need:

```
$ print -rl 'bundle exec rake db:'{drop,create,migrate}
bundle exec rake db:drop
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

`x{a,b}y` creates 2 arguments where `{a,b}` is replaced with `a` in the first and `b` in the second.

If you wanted the above to be executed, you could pipe it to `sh` (or `zsh` though there's no `zsh` specific code in it), or you could write:

```
eval 'bundle exec rake db:'{drop,create,migrate}$'\n'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was also able to pipe it like so and it worked as well. `print -rl 'bundle exec rake db:'{drop,create,migrate} | zsh`

Answer (score 2):

No, it's expanded to:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

From `zsh` documentation, [braces expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) section:

> A string of the form ‘foo{xx,yy,zz}bar’ is expanded to the individual
>   words ‘fooxxbar’, ‘fooyybar’ and ‘foozzbar’. Left-to-right order is
>   preserved. This construct may be nested. Commas may be quoted in order
>   to include them literally in a word.